# How To download the article content as pdf in joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla

Is there any extension except Phoca PDF.
I want to download the article content by providing it any link to save the content as a pdf file.

Comment: Please anyone Suggest me any extension or any other way.

Comment: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/print-a-pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either download a [phocapdf](http://www.phoca.cz/phocapdf) or you can create a view for this as suggested [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_PDF_views)